# Xpath text extraction between 2 keywords

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Is there an xpath expression that return the text available between 2 keywords?

For example we have a span like the following:

```
<b>Specialty: </b>PO<br/><b>Job Function: </b>RN<br/><br/><b>Qualifications/Duties</b><br/>Texas Health Presbyterian Allen is currently in search of a Registered Nurse to help meet the growing needs of our Day Surgery Department to work PRN in Day Surgery and also float to PACU.<br/><br/><b>Basic Qualifications:</b><br/><br/>*Graduate of an accredited school of nursing<br/>*Valid RN license in the state of Texas<br/>*BLS<br/>*ACLS<br/>*PALS within 6 months of hire<br/>*Minimum of 1 - 3 years experience as RN in Day Surgery, PACU, Outpatient Surgery, or ICU<br/>*Strong organizational skills and ability to function in a fast paced work environment<br/>*Ability to accept responsibility and show initiative to work without direct supervision<br/>*A high degree of confidentiality, positive interpersonal skills and ability to function in a fast-paced environment<br/><br/><b>Preferred Qualifications:</b><br/><br/>*Three years RN experience in Outpatient Surgery along with some ICU experience.<br/>*PALS<br/>*PACU , Endoscopy or Ambulatory setting<br/>*IV Conscious Sedation<br/><br/><b>Hours/Schedule:</b><br/><br/>*Variable<br/><br/>J2WPeriop<br/><br/><b>Entity Information</b><br/>Texas Health Presbyterian Hospital Allen is a 73-bed, acute-care hospital serving the northern Collin County area since 2000. Hospital services include women’s care, a Level II neonatal intensive care unit, orthopedics, pediatrics, wound care and sleep medicine. Texas Health Allen, a Pathway to Excellence® designated hospital by the American Nurses Credentialing Center, has more than 500 physicians on its medical staff practicing in more than 25 specialties. Texas Health Allen is a World Health Organization-designated "Baby-Friendly Hospital" and was the first hospital in Texas to receive the distinction. The hospital is a Level IV trauma center and an Accredited Chest Pain Center by the Society of Chest Pain Centers, which makes our facility intensely qualified to serve our community and your professional aspirations.<br/>
```

I would like to know if we can define an xpath to return all the text that is available between 2 keywords say "Qualifications/Duties" and "Entity Information"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but don't expect a nicely formatted output, the markup is messy and the expression might need some slight tweaks for whether you also want the nodes with "Basic Qualifications:" or not (this version skips them, it only takes "naked" text nodes).

```
//text()[preceding-sibling::*[text()='Qualifications/Duties'] and following-sibling::*[text()='Entity Information']]
```

And it means:

```
//text()
SELECT EVERY TEXT NODE
   [
    THAT
    preceding-sibling::*[text()='Qualifications/Duties']
    IS PRECEDED BY A NODE WITH TEXT = "Qualifications/Duties"
    and following-sibling::*[text()='Entity Information'
    AND FOLLOWED BY A NODE WITH TEXT = "Entity Information"
   ]
```

the output for your example:

```
Texas Health Presbyterian Allen is currently in search of a Registered Nurse to help meet the growing needs of our Day Surgery Department to work PRN in Day Surgery and also float to PACU.
*Graduate of an accredited school of nursing
*Valid RN license in the state of Texas
*BLS
*ACLS
*PALS within 6 months of hire
*Minimum of 1 - 3 years experience as RN in Day Surgery, PACU, Outpatient Surgery, or ICU
*Strong organizational skills and ability to function in a fast paced work environment
*Ability to accept responsibility and show initiative to work without direct supervision
*A high degree of confidentiality, positive interpersonal skills and ability to function in a fast-paced environment
*Three years RN experience in Outpatient Surgery along with some ICU experience.
*PALS
*PACU , Endoscopy or Ambulatory setting
*IV Conscious Sedation
*Variable
J2WPeriop
```

Comment: Can you please look into my problem and solve me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189178/match-an-element-with-a-dynamic-attribute-value